# Javascript: make rectangle grow upwards

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a code that has a bar rise while a certain condition is met, and if not, it falls back down. I figured the best way to do this is to increment the height and margin-top inversely so that as the margin-top decreases, the height can increase, creating the illusion that the bar was only ever rising. However, it seems that the top of the bar is stuck and changing the margin-top doesn't change anything. Here's my code:

```
function progresMove() {
    if (playerMargin >= marginRange[0] && playerMargin <= marginRange[1]) {
        progressHeight += .75;
        progressMargin -= .75;
        progress.style.cssText = "margin-top: " + progressMargin + "px";
        progress.style.cssText = "height: " + progressHeight + "px";
    } else {
        progressHeight -= 1.5;
        progressMargin += 1.5;
        progress.style.cssText = "margin-top: " + progressMargin + "px";
        progress.style.cssText = "height: " + progressHeight + "px";
    }
}
```

This function is called every .05 seconds, and acts upon already created HTML elements with some styling:

```
width: 24px;
    background-color: #64DD17;
    margin-left: 3px;
    display: block;
```

All it does at the moment is push the rectangle down.

Also, it is inside a div within a div if that makes a difference. I've tried floating them, putting them in inline-block, and having overflow be hidden, and it doesn't make a difference.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Give the parent `position: relative` and the element itself `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`. That way the element is always aligned with the bottom of the parent. But you have to specify height and width of the parent in some way, otherwise it will collapse if the children are positioned absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `cssText`:

```
progress.style.cssText = "margin-top: " + progressMargin + "px";
progress.style.cssText = "height: " + progressHeight + "px";
```

with:

```
progress.style.marginTop = progressMargin + "px";
progress.style.height = progressHeight + "px";
```

#### Explanation:

You're overwriting `cssText` value, so there's no rule for `margin-top` at the end of your function.

Consider following snippet:

```js
div1.style.cssText = "color: red";
div1.style.cssText = "background-color: yellow";

div2.style.cssText = "color: yellow";
div2.style.cssText += ";background-color: red";

div3.style.color = "red";
div3.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

```html
<div id="div1">div 1</div>
<div id="div2">div 2</div>
<div id="div3">div 3</div>
```

First div's background becomes yellow, but text is still black. In second and third div both changes are applied